# Python profiling - What are the columns in runsnakerun output?

Tags: python, profiling

This may be really obvious but just wanted to make sure I understand what the columns are in runsnakerun.

Name, Calls, RCalls, Local, /Call, Cum, /Call, File, Line, Directory

Here are some that I think I understand

Name - name of function being called

1. Calls - number of calls?
2. File - file where the function is stored
3. Line - Line in File where the function is defined
4. Directory - directory of file with function definition

The ones I don't feel comfortable venturing a guess are the rest:

1. RCalls
2. Local
3. /Call
4. Cum
5. /Call

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at my answer yet?  It contains an example, which makes it easier to see how the different columns work in practice...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to illustrate is with an example -- suppose you have the following program (stored in profileme.py, but broken into pieces for clarity):

```
def topfunction():
    tinyfunction()
    for i in range(100000):
        manytinyfunction()
```

**Calls** is simple -- how many times this function was called directly.  Of course as you select the items on the left side, those numbers will change, reflecting the number of times the function was called by the selected function.  `manytinyfunction` will get called 100,000 times, so calls will be 100,000.  `tinyfunction` will get called once, so its calls will be 1.

```
    for i in range(10):
        recursive(100)
```

**rcalls** is similar, but it also includes calls that happened while a call was being executed.  Notice for `recursive` that calls is only 10, but rcalls is 1010 (definition below, but it calls itself n times if its argument is n.

```
    alllocal()
    allcumulative()
```

Similarly, **local** includes all the time spent in the function itself, not counting calls out to other functions.  Here `alllocal` has a large value here, but `allcumulative` has nothing here, since it fobs its work onto `subfunction`.

```
def tinyfunction():
    pass

def manytinyfunction():
    pass
```

The **/Call next to the local** simply breaks the local value above down per call, so `manytinyfunction` has a little time overall, but a very very tiny number in the local /call, since each call is really cheap.

```
def alllocal():
    for i in range(1000):
        for j in range(1000):
            for k in range(1000):
                pass
```

For `alllocal` the /call will be huge both for local and for cumulative, since this function is so expensive, and all the expense is local.

```
def allcumulative():
    for i in range(1000):
        subfunction()

def subfunction():
    for j in range(1000):
        for k in range(1000):
            pass
```

The **/Call next to cumulative** is the same as the /call for local, except that, like cumulative itself, it has the complete cost of all calls out from the function itself included.  So the local /call number was tiny for `allcumulative`, but large for `alllocal`.  Not so for the cumulative /call, which will be the same in both cases.

```
def recursive(n):
    if n > 0:
        return recursive(n-1)
    else:
        return 0
```

The definition for `recursive` is provided for completeness

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    topfunction()
```

After profiling it and running runsnake:

```
python -m cProfile -o profileme.out profileme.py 
runsnake profileme.out
```

So, notice that `alllocal` has a large value for both local and cumulative, where as `allcumulative` is sharply different.  Notice that `recursive` is the same in both columns -- calls to yourself are counted.

The **Callees** button on the bottom lets you figure out what other functions the selected function is calling, while **Callers** lets you figure out who's calling the selected function.

Comment: could you format the answer to be more readable, maybe moving text above the code? to be honest I never managed to get through it all with ease. Info seems a bit convoluted.

Comment: I think the best answer would look like @interskh with an example, comment below each item, as you tried to do, makes sense?

Comment: Is this better?  I've interspersed the code and comments, and tried to clarify

Comment: yup much better. I think if you add highlighting and emphasis to the functions and Calls etc it will be perfect and will accept

Comment: I highlighted the function references, and bolded the first time a particular part of the UI was talked about -- highlighting them all looked like angry fruit salad.  Enjoy

Comment: @Makoto -- is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 7):

Here is my understanding:

- `RCalls` number of recursive calls
- `Local` Total time spent on local execution (without calling another method)
- `/Call` Local time per call
- `Cum` Total cumulative time
- `/Call` Cumulative time per call

Comment: Though I can see why the bounty wants more detail, this certainly answers the question!